# Enable selective muting of AirTag alerts in designated areas

Tags: airtag

I've equipped my children with AirTags for their keys to ensure their belongings are trackable. However, we've encountered an issue where the AirTags sometimes emit sound during their classes at school. I suspect this happens because the students are required to turn off their phones, but the teacher's phone remains on. The AirTags seem to activate their sound when in proximity to an unknown iPhone. Is there a way to disable this sound feature when the AirTags are at a specific location, such as the school?

Answer (score 1):

Apple designed all AirTags to be located by people who don’t own them to prevent unwanted tracking.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212227

Your school policy is likely increasing the odds they will chime - instead of turning off the children’s phones - they should be muted or in a focus state so they tell the AirTags the “owner” is close. They should also ensure your keys and tags do not move or get disturbed when the phones are “off”.

> An AirTag, AirPods Pro (2nd generation) charging case, or Find My network accessory that isn't with its owner for a period of time will emit a sound when it's moved.

If someone with an NFC capable device sends a probe to detect nearby AirTags, nothing will silence them by design unless the batteries are removed from the AirTag. Someone (another child or adult) can also detect your AirTags and make them play a sound on demand.